# "Error in sys.excepthook" PyQt5.10.1Python 3.6

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6

i have a custom sys.excepthook in my main.py:

```
def application_exception_hook(type_, value, tb):
    lines = format_exception(type_, value, tb)
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
    sys.excepthook = sys._excepthook
    sys.exit(1)

sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook
sys.excepthook = application_exception_hook
```

In case of a unhandled exception the console output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):


Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Replacing...

```
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

...with...

```
    print(lines)
```

...gives me this output:

```
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "D:\\...\\framework.py", line 144, in openNesting\n    foo = 123 / 0\n', 'ZeroDivisionError: division by zero\n']Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):


Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

So, in both cases there is an "Error in sys.excepthook", while in the first case the error already appears before printing out all the interesting attributes. I would like to know what could cause "Error in sys.excepthook" and how I can get ONLY this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\...\\framework.py", line 144, in openNesting
foo = 123 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I could not find any solved topic adressing this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: There was an error in a method that duplicates stdout and stderr messages to a QtTextEdit. After manually tracing it down everything now works as expected.